# Matrix $I + 2 A A^T$ is nonsingular for any A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose A is $m\times n$ matrix with real entries. Could you prove that $\det (I + 2 A A^T) \neq 0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $S$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite. Then $S=U\Lambda U^T$ for some orthogonal $U$ and diagonal $\Lambda$. Then $I+S = I+U \Lambda U^T= U (I+\Lambda) U^T$. Hence $\det (I+S) = \det (I+ \Lambda) = \prod_k (1+\lambda_k)$, where the $\lambda_k$ are diagonal elements of $\Lambda$. Since $S$ is positive semi-definite, $\lambda_k \ge 0$, hence $\det (I+S) \ge 1$.

In this example, $S=2A A^T$, which is easily seen to be symmetric and positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 3):

If $(I+2AA^T)x=0$, then $0=x^T(I+2AA^T)x=\|x\|^2+2\|A^Tx\|^2$ and hence $x=0$. Therefore $(I+2AA^T)x=0$ has only the trivial solution. Consequently, $I+2AA^T$ is invertible and its determinant is nonzero.